# Next.js: Strange Error When Re-validating Paths

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a Next app with a API endpoint for editing a resource (using the pages-based system, not the app-based one).  Everything works great with it, except that after editing a resource, when I go to view it (or re-edit it) I see the old version.

After consulting the documentation, it seems like I can use the `revalidatePath` to tell Next to clear the cache for that route.  However, when I try to use it, like so:

```
// pages/api/resource.js

const handler = async (request, response) => {
    const id = await saveStuff(request);
    revalidatePath(`/resource/[name]`);
    revalidatePath(`/resource/[name]/edit`);
    response.send(JSON.stringify({ id }));
}
```

I get an error about a *completely different* function: `revalidateTag`.

```
> Error: Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag
> /resource/[name]
>     at revalidateTag (/home/me/project/next/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/revalidate-tag.js:15:15)
>     at revalidatePath (/home/me/project/next/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/revalidate-path.js:13:45)
>     at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/resource.js:83:67)
>     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I've never used `revalidatePath` before, so I'm probably using it wrong somehow, but I have no idea what I could be doing to cause this error.  Alternatively, if there is some other mechanism by which I could force Next to clear its cache for a specific page, that would also be helpful.

**EDIT:**

I looked at the source code, and it seems `revalidatePath` calls `revalidateTag` (with the path as the tag).  The error comes from the end of this code:

```
function revalidateTag(tag) {
  const staticGenerationAsyncStorage = fetch.__nextGetStaticStore == null ? void 0 : fetch.__nextGetStaticStore();
      const store = staticGenerationAsyncStorage == null ? void 0 : staticGenerationAsyncStorage.getStore();
      if (!store || !store.incrementalCache) {
          throw new Error(`Invariant: static generation store missing in revalidateTag ${tag}`);
      }
```

In other words, it looks like the `staticGenerationAsyncStorage` isn't there on the `fetch`, which suggests that Next hasn't patched the function yet.  But this code is being called from an API route function, so it seems like Next should have had a chance to patch `fetch` already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was just confusion with the Next.js documentation (unfortunately it's really easy to find a Next.js documentation page through Google, and not realize that it applies to the old/new Next, when you're looking for new/old Next info).

In this case, it turns out the stand-alone `revalidatePath` is only for `app` directory pages/routes.  For `pages` directory routes you need to use:

```
response.revalidate(path);
```